# Полное копирование списка

Tags: c#

Если взять список структур

```
struct DataStruct
{
    // Поля структуры
}

List<DataStruct> dataStruct = new List<DataStruct>();
```

то список копий получается просто:

```
var structCopy = new List<DataStruct>(dataStruct);
```

Если же взять список классов

```
class DataClass
{
    // Поля класса
}

List<DataClass> dataClass = new List<DataClass>();
```

то тем же образом список копий уже не получается

```
var classCopy = new List<DataClass>(dataClass);
```

потому что, хотя и создается новый список, он содержит ссылки на прежние объекты. Я не нашел встроенного метода для копирования списков. Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: На самом деле, глубокое клонирование нужно даже для случая структур, потому что структура вполне себе может содержать _ссылку_ на класс.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

На самом деле, список копируется в обоих случаях. Проблема с классом состоит в том, что простое его копирование не приводит к копированию содержимого (это reference-тип). Прежде чем копировать список классов, стоит научится копировать (а, вернее, клонировать) один конкретный класс. Это делается реализацией метода `Clone`. Чтобы не копировать руками все поля, можно использовать метод `MemberwiseClone` класса `System.Object`. Но если эти поля являются reference-типами, то они также не будут клонированы, вам придётся вызвать у них метод `Clone` (а, возможно, и реализовать его) руками.

Когда вы сможете клонировать экземпляры вашего класса, вы сможете пройти по элементам и клонировать каждый, создав новый список. Несколько интересных реализаций приведены [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222598/how-do-i-clone-a-generic-list-in-c).